# Click bubbling all messed on radio buttons

Tags: knockout.js

http://jsfiddle.net/7kb7n/

```
    function StorewideSaleModel() {

    this.radioOff = ko.observable(""+1);

}

ko.applyBindings(new StorewideSaleModel());
```

So, what I am trying to do here is enable/disable the text box depending on the radio button. I also assigned a click event to the div so if I click anywhere else in that div, the button gets checked. That all works fine.

BUT, if I click the radio button itself, it doesn't get checked, BUT the rest of the UI still updates. If you check the value, then the radio button goes back (magically) to the old value. How does it even remember the old value I have no idea.

So I tried clickBubble: false, and the event STILL bubbled to the enclosing div. I used alerts to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Knockout prevents the click event from taking any default action.

So you need to return `true` from your click event handler to [allow the default click action](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action):

```
data-bind="click: function() { radioOff('2'); return true;}"
```

and

```
data-bind="click: function() {radioOff('1'); return true;} "
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68yx4/).

Comment: Thanks! I wasted a whole day with every possible combination of returns except that. Which is a good thing since now I know the reason behind it.